# changing no_proxy environment variable value with awk

Tags: linux, awk, grep

I want to read IP address of all interface and set it to `no_proxy` variable in centos machine.

i can do it manual by running `ifconfig`

this is the ip address in one of my vagrant box,

```
192.168.10.2
10.0.1.13
192.168.84.18
```

but i have around 13 boxes and ips are dynamically set everytime box is brought up.

i tried,

`ifconfig | grep 192*` and it gives me ip but not of all the interfaces available.

how can i set all the interface ip and assign them to `no_proxy` variable?

Comment: do all your vagrant machines use centos?

Comment: yes at this moment they are

Comment: Isn't `ip addr show` the canonical way of listing interface details in Linux these days?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `awk` with `grep` to get the ip address in your CentOS machines, and then `tr` command to remove `\n`

```
noip="$(ifconfig | grep inet | awk '{print $2","}' | tr -d '\n')"
```

it will give you,

```
192.168.10.2,10.0.1.13,192.168.84.18,
```

export it as follows including `localhost` and loopback address, i.e. `127.0.0.1`,

```
export no_proxy=${noip}localhost,127.0.0.1
```

So your complete code will be,

```
noip="$(ifconfig | grep inet | awk '{print $2","}' | tr -d '\n')"
export no_proxy=${noip}localhost,127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I grabbed regular expression from https://www.brianparsons.net/FindIPAddresseswithawk/

```
~$ ips=$(ifconfig | awk '{match($0,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/); if(RLENGTH > 0) { ip = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); print ip}}')
~$ echo $ips
127.0.0.1 10.65.240.107
```